# Update variables at every change, regardless of timeframe

Tags: pine-script

I would like to display a label with the current `close` that is colored according to the change with respect to the very last (i.e., intra-bar) value of `close`, thereby replicating the way a symbol's values are colored in a watchlist (at every single change of value)

However, it seems that Pine Script will only update user/script variables at the start of a new bar (with respect to the chart's timeframe resolution).

Although `close` will always return the most current value, there is no way (that I have found) to access the ***very last*** `close`— only `close[1]`, which is the last ***bar's*** close and not the truly-previous value of `close`.  I would need something along the lines of `close[0,1]`, of the form `source[bar_index, array_index_of_changes_within_bar_index]`.

I have tried several ways to get around this: arrays, combinations of var and non-var variables, `security()` at `1s` resolutions (which would have been a subpar solution but which, regardless, Pine Script does not allow).

Any suggestions as to whether or not this is achievable in Pine Script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `varip` declared array like so to do the close comparison intrabar

```
var label close_label = label.new(x = bar_index, y = close, style = label.style_label_left, size = size.normal, textcolor = color.white)
varip float[] intrabar_closes = array.new_float()

array.unshift(intrabar_closes, close)
if array.size(intrabar_closes) > 2
    array.pop(intrabar_closes)
col = array.size(intrabar_closes) > 1 ? array.get(intrabar_closes, 0) >= array.get(intrabar_closes, 1) ? color.lime : color.red : na
label.set_xy(close_label, x = bar_index, y = close)
label.set_color(close_label, color = col)
label.set_text(close_label, text = tostring(close))
```

Comment: I am revisiting this idea, and want to run some calculations based on ``array.get(intrabar_closes, 0)`` and ``array.get(intrabar_closes, 1)`` (for ex., calculating the $ or % change between them).  However, I am running into problems.  

I am able to return/display a value for ``array.get(intrabar_closes, 0)``, but if I try to display/return a value for ``array.get(intrabar_closes, 1)`` I am breaking the code. Why does this line not work, for the label text: ``label.set_text(close_label, text = tostring(array.get(intrabar_closes, 0) - array.get(intrabar_closes, 1)))``? Thanks again.

Comment: I'm guessing you're probably getting the index error occur and it's due to on the first update, there only exists one value in the array. Like for the `col` variable, you need to test first if there is more than 1 value in the array.